# How do responsive CSS float elements position vertically when width is reduced

Tags: css-float, responsive-design

I've messed around with a few responsive designs, and I'm curious about what CSS properties determine how `float` elements are positioned vertically when the overall resolution is reduced and they are scrunched together.

For example, if I have a `div` block with `float:left` and a `div` block with `float:right`, which of those end up on top when the max width of the container is reduced to the point where they can't fit inline anymore.

If you look at my fiddle, the left side element ends up on top when you reduce the width to the point where they both can't fit.  Is there a property that makes it so?  Does it do it in order?  Is there anything I can add to the right div block that would make it above the left element when width is reduced?

http://jsfiddle.net/JXXLK/

Many thanks SO

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to put your right div on top when the window is rescaled is to define it first in your html code:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="rightside">
       RIDE SIDE HOMBRE!                
    </div>
    <div class="leftside">
       LEFT SIDE DUDE!
    </div>
</div>​
```

I'm not sure how this can be controlled using purely css properties.

Comment: Absolutely.  I was just curious about the nature of floats, and if any CSS properties could determine this, aside from the order of the HTML itself.  Thanks for your input!